# Multiple joins with variables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example of my DB:

```
ID     APP     USER_ID    SESSION_ID  LOCAL_TIME  CONTEXT  ACTION       VALUE
141    App1    userID1     session1   2019-07-18   Player   Name      PlayerName1
141    App1    userID1     session1   2019-07-18   Player    XP          486
141    App1    userID1     session2   2019-07-18   App     BuildNum     11184
452    App1    userID4     session1   2019-07-18   Player   Name      PlayerName2
```

I have a query I run in my `ti_userevent` database that combines users play session lengths from multiple play sessions and instead returns the total play length for each player between a set time and date (Instead of 4 sessions for Player 1, it returns 1 and gives me the total play length of all 4 sessions).

This query allows me to set the date and time range for the data I am looking for in MetaBase, and returns the player ID, player name and total play length across multiple sessions for each user within the timeframe provided.

This is the query.

```
SELECT t2.playername,
      (EXTRACT(EPOCH
          FROM ( MAX(t.local_time) - MIN(t.local_time)) ::INTERVAL)/60)::integer as duration
              FROM ti_userevent t
          JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT t2.value as playerName, t2.session_id
              FROM ti_userevent t2
                  WHERE context = 'Player' 
                  AND
                  action = 'Name'
                      [[AND local_time >= {{StartTime}}::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific']]
                      [[AND local_time < {{EndTime}}::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific']]
              ) t2
          ON t2.session_id = t.session_id
  GROUP BY t2.playername;
```

Example Data:

```
       User ID        User Name   Play Length of all sessions
        ID1             Name 1          105
        ID2             Name 2          215
        ID3             Name 3          352
```

But, I would also like to get their lifetime XP from the Query. The problem is, this info is stored in the same table!

In order to get the players lifeime XP I run the following, this only gives me their lifetime experience based on the build number.

```
SELECT
    session_id
    ,context
    ,action
    ,value
FROM 
    ti_userevent
WHERE 
        context = 'Player'
    AND action = 'XP'
    AND session_id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT session_id
            FROM 
                ti_userevent
            WHERE 
                action = 'BuildNum'
                and value = {{BuildNum}})
```

Example Data:

```
    user_id    session_id    action    value
    ID1         session1       XP      10587 
    ID2         session1       XP      845214
    ID3         session1       XP      484348
```

What I would like is to combine the two queries into the first Play session length query. I would like to have them all run off the timeframe range in the first query and also have the BuildNum variable in the second query... I have tried several times and am having a hard time getting it to return the data I am after.

What I am after (With time and BuildNum variables):

```
    User ID          User Name   Play Length of all sessions    Player XP
        ID1             Name 1          105                      1324154
        ID2             Name 2          215                      84415
        ID3             Name 3          352                      4784512
```

Ultimately, I just want to be able to add the `context = 'Player'AND action = 'XP'` to the first query, but I can't do it without using a join and I am having a hard time doing it with these variables...

I am not the best with SQL so I am hoping someone on here could help me. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please add sample input data according to your expected result to your question.

Comment: Hey @etsuhisa I added the sample DB data, is that what you were after?